# Calculate sum of ONB

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Here's a homework question:

Let ${u_1, \ldots, u_n}$ be an ONB in $C^n$. Assuming that $n$ is even, compute

$$||u_1 - u_2 + u_3 -\cdots - u_n||$$

I have no idea how to solve this. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: "ONB" is not a standard abbreviation -- in any case, I have not used it or seen it being used until now. To make the post self-contained, you should perhaps expand it to "orthonormal basis".

Comment: I've seen "ONB" before, but without some context would not have immediately realized what it means.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n=2p$. We have 
\begin{align*}
\lVert u_1-u_2+\cdots -u_n\rVert^2 &=\lVert \sum_{j=1}^pu_{2j-1}-u_{2j}\rVert^2 \\
&=\sum_{j=1}^p\lVert u_{2j-1}-u_{2j}\rVert^2\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^p 2=2p,
\end{align*}
so $\lVert u_1-u_2+\cdots -u_n\rVert=\sqrt n$.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by expanding out $\|x\|^2$, or perhaps you have seen a formula
for $\|\sum_j c_j u_j\|$.